# Focus on keyboard tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an accessible navigation menu with nested submenu items, the issue I am having is that while tabbing through the navigation does highlight all inner links, it does not trigger the dropdown's display; I am not sure if this is from a failure to trigger focus or not, though that is what I suspect.

The html is roughly along the lines of:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
 <li> Link </li>
 ...
 <li> Link
   <ul>
    <li> inner link </li>
    ...
   </ul>
 </li>
```

Then my jQuery is:

```
$( "ul.sf-menu li").focus(function(){
 this.toggleClass("over");
});
$( "ul.sf-menu li ul").focus(function(){
 this.toggleClass("over");
});
```

Where the class `over` sets the display to block.

**EDIT**

I do have tab indexes declared on list elements with the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain this is not what tab is supposed to do, but instead of using jQuery to add a class, you can use the pseado css selector `:focus`.

```
ul.sf-menu li:focus{ /* Code to fold it open */ }
```

Comment: To clarify the tabbing is for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`focusin`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) events because the `focus` and `blur` events don't bubble.

```js
$('.item').on({
  'focusin mouseenter': function () {
    $(this).addClass('open');
  },
  'focusout mouseleave': function () {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.item > ul {
  position: fixed;
  right: 100%;
}

.item.open > ul {
  position: static;
  right: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Additionally, elements with `display: none` cannot receive focus, so your code:

```
$("ul.sf-menu li ul").focus(...)
```

can never execute, even if you update to use the `focusin` event.

Comment: You are right about that, and have created the exact functionality I am hoping for, however it still isn't working. It seems instead of focusing the list elements, it is focusing the anchor tags within.

Comment: @NathanGilford, what's the point of focusing the list elements at all? They're not actionable. These implicitly opening menus are also not a great choice for touch screens. Consider just using buttons to toggle submenus open/closed.

Comment: I get your point, unfortunately had I been involved in this site from the beginning accessibility would of been handled at that point, I've just been assigned to a poorly made site to begin with. The list elements are what trigger the existing hover effects, I just need to create focus effects that do the same.

Comment: @NathanGilford, it seems you're asking for more than what's in your question. If there's additional context that's relevant for an acceptable answer, please update your question to include it. At this point I've provided a demo that should show you *how* to write the code you need, but I have no intention of writing your code for you.

Comment: On the contrary, I think you projected your opinion of how the site should of initially been coded on what my question was, the modification you suggested, while semantic and technically correct did not resolve the problem, and I am continuing to look for a solution, I do not need you or anyone else to write code for me, just help me understand why the code I have written doesn't work as I expected. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanGilford, my demo wasn't intended to be a modification of your code, it was intended as an example of using `focusin` and `focusout`.

Comment: @NathanGilford, re-reading your question it seems that you may be running into another issue, namely that you're listening for focus on elements that can never be focused (`display: none`).

Comment: that makes sense, and could be the case, I don't think using visibility instead of display will be possible, have you seen this type of issue before?